# Google API – send email with default signature

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on mobile app that works as a simple gmail client. Is there any way how to add user's default signature (that you can set in gmail settings) when sending a message using google API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of April 2017, GMail API supports manipulating the signature via SendAs API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs
The workflow would be:

- get the default signature
- add it to the email body when sending message.